# how can my content can animate using tympanus example on my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to have animation on my content i searched whole day and got something to work on it.I used same technique as they used everything is seems same still when i scroll my website there is no animation on content after slider. 
[Demo example](https://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index2.html)
[My website](http://www.kamran.tahirhassan.com)

Comment: You posted this an hour ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918772/on-scroll-down-move-up-content-animations-of-boostrap-4-card-content You need to try something and come here to ask a specific question with a problem you encountered. And include the relevant code in the post itself - don't just link to your website.

Comment: yes i did sorry i thought that post must be already deleted since i could not give complete detail of my own efforts. i have used link because there was few js files those had no cdn that is why i choose to upload it live that is not official site so its fine if my issue can be sort out. Hope there should be no matter to do it i am deleting that post just now. Thanks

Comment: Your website has the following script errors:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` `Uncaught ReferenceError: imagesLoaded is not defined`

Comment: i think demo and my website both used same method what can be sollution for error

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the [imagesloaded.js](https://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/js/imagesloaded.js) file used in the example.  You need to reference this script in your code.

Comment: i have added imagesloaded.js locally still no change.

Comment: You will also need a `opacity: 0;` for your `.card` class so that the list items start out transparent.

Comment: no result it just invisible my card nothing else